# How do I link 3 models in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I have 3 tables. User, Post & Comments.

A User & Post are linked together as a User can have many posts and it fetches the user-id every time the user posts.

Comment table has user id and post id to it.

User can have multiple comments, and a post can have multiple comments. I tried using this but it says

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany::associate()
```

Here's my code for linking.

Store method for CommentController:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'text'=>'required'
        ]);

        $comment = new Comment;
        $comment->text = $request->get('text');
        $comment->user()->associate($request->user());

        $comment->save();

        return redirect('/home');
    }
```

Here are my relation queries. In my post model, I have this:

```
public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
```

In my user model I have this:

```
public function comment()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
```

In my comment model, I have this:

```
public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,Post::class);
    }
```

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: A comment may only be associated with a single post and a single user so I don't see the need to link them both at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

You are using belongsToMany() incorrectly - you cannot attach it to multiple models that way, as the second parameter it is expecting (if provided) is a database table name.

Each comment, presumably, belongsTo() a single User, and belongsTo() a single Post, in which case it should say so - in your Comment model :

```
public function user() {
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function post() { 
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

There is no associate() method, either - I think you may be thinking of attach(), but that's unnecessary here, as that's on oneToMany / ManyToMany relationships where there is an intermediate table. In this instance, since the Comment belongsTo() a single User, then your comments table just needs a user_id column with the relationship to the users table, and in your store() method you can just :

```
$comment = new Comment;
$comment->text = $request->get('text');
$comment->user_id = $request->user()->id;
$comment->save();
```

Comment: I did this, and I get this error every time I post a comment

The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.

Comment: THat's unrelated to your original question - check your routes file.